# Undo clear selected from workspace mapping p4v

Tags: p4v

I was trying to move my workspace root around and did clear workspace mappings in p4v.  What this did was clear every subfolder from the mappings.  Then when I try to include the whole tree, it only includes the selected folder, since all the subfolders were cleared.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

It may not list them, but if you are including the top folder "recursively" (i.e. follow the directory name with a slash and "..."), it includes all subdirectories without listing them explicitly.

To add the top directory in the "View Workspace Mappings as Tree" view, navigate to your depot or the highest-level directory you want to add.  Right-click the directory and choose "Include Tree".  Expand the tree views to verify that they are included.

If you're used to the "Workspace mapping as text", add the depot and client paths of the top-level directory that contains the subdirectories you want.  Make sure the mappings are "recursive" and include all files and directories below by appending "..." after each side.

Ex:

Suppose you want to include dir1 and dir2, both of which reside under top_dir. Add this line to your workspace mapping:

```
//depot1/top_dir/... //myclient/top_dir/...
```

This will include //depot1/top_dir/dir1 and //depot1/top_dir/dir2, and all other files and directories under "top_dir".